# How can I get return values from C# .DLLs in LabVIEW 2012?

Tags: c#, dll, labview

I'm currently working on exporting a .DLL library file in C# in Visual Studio 2010 to LabVIEW 2012. The class does a color transform from RGB to HSL values, and I've been successful in implementing Constructor and Invoke nodes in the LabVIEW project to call the .DLL file.

So far I can input numbers for the RGB values into the Invoke node, but I'm having trouble getting HSL output values; the option doesn't appear in the drop-down box for the node.

I'm relatively fresh to C# (and programming in general) and I think I've spotted where the input function is in the .DLL, but as for the output function I've no clue how to generate it, much less in such a way that LabVIEW can export it cleanly. I figure if I can input values, I should be able to get those HSL outputs as well.

Below is the C# code snippet in question. The rest of the class is the formula for the transform itself, so I don't think it's too relevant.

```
public class QuickColorTransform
{
    byte _R;
    byte _G;
    byte _B;

    byte _H;

    public byte H
    {
        get { return _H; }
        set { _H = value; }
    }
    byte _S;

    public byte S
    {
        get { return _S; }
        set { _S = value; }
    }
    byte _L;

    public byte L
    {
        get { return _L; }
        set { _L = value; }
    }

    public QuickColorTransform()
    {
        SetupLookups();
    }

    public void SetColor(byte Red, byte Green, byte Blue)
    {
        _R = Red;
        _G = Green;
        _B = Blue;
        Transform();
    }

    public void SetColor(Color ColorIn)
    {
        _R = ColorIn.R;
        _G = ColorIn.G;
        _B = ColorIn.B;
        Transform();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any good reason you can't just do the RGB to HSL transform in LabVIEW?

Comment: I'm not satisfied with LabVIEW's (and by extension Vision Builder's) algorithm in converting RGB to HSI. This code snippet was taken from an object detection program which has provided much better results, and I'd like to get the best of both worlds - LabVIEW's/Vision Builder's versatility and ease of use and the effectiveness of this secondary program.

Comment: But could you code your algorithm in LabVIEW instead of C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created public HSL getters, and LabVIEW knows how to access it. Just use a property node in your VI, and link it to the object reference after the call to `SetColor()`, H S and L will be in the choice list of the property node.